# Yet another how to bypass "verify your account this device was reset"

Tags: factory-reset, google-account, frp

On my phone (Alcatel mt6737m aka Optus X Spirit, android 6.0) I had screen lock set up, and also had "require PIN on startup" (when it asks for pin on every reboot, even before showing unlock screen). And I had google account, which I only set up because it's required for google play. I don't remember username or password for the google account. I still remember the old PIN for the phone.

I did a factory reset via boot menu. Now I got this "verify your account this device was reset" message.

I managed to open settings using one of the exploits I found here, but even if I do factory reset via settings menu, it still asks me to "verify your account". I also tried to set PIN to my old PIN and then disable PIN and do factory reset from settings - no change.

I can start Chrome or almost any other app (if i place shortcut on the lock screen), can modify settings, can start file browser, install apk from sdcard. I can not create a new google account - it shows me the same  "verify your account" screen. I can not enble developer options.

Any ideas?

Comment: phone is not rooted

Comment: from the settings: android security patch level 5 nov 2017

Answer (score 0):

I have written many articles covering FRP Unlocking.. it eventually lead me to write a guide on XDA Forums...

Here.. [FRP Lock Removal Methods for All Androids..](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=79032672)
..

I still need to format the post, but main information is up...

One addition i didn't add is a new discovery...

• Build prop contains the path to FRP Partition and removing the build prop line will remove FRP Locks...

So edit `system/build.prop` and remove the prop `ro.frp.pst=/dev/...` ---

Or Comment it out with #   `# ro.frp.pst=....`

Please read it all to understand FRP ...

Hope this helps to get an Answer for your specific device.

Here's example.
Method 2 - MTK Device's ( Old Method, Use New .)

- Download FRP Destroyer.zip
- Extract FRP Destroyer.zip
- Open Android_Scatter File.
- Edit FRP isDownload to True
- Save Android_scatter.txt.
- Open new Scatter in SP Flash Tool
- Unselect all partitions.
- Select only FRP location
- Choose blank_frp.img  from FRP Destroyer folder.
- DOWNLOAD ONLY The FRP Partition.
- Reboot device.

Alternatively,
• Use SP Flash Tool & Wipe the FRP Partition Manually as per your scatter file information for FRP.p